# Select rows which have no match in other table

Tags: mysql

This query seemed pretty simple to start with.

```
#table - user
user_id - full_name  - image
 1        Jon-1        Jon-placeholder.png
 2        Aax-2        Max-placeholder.png
 3        Lie-3        Lie-placeholder.png
 4        Man-4        Man-placeholder.png
 5        Nik-5        Nik-placeholder.png
 6        Led-6        Led-placeholder.png
 7        Neo-7        Neo-placeholder.png

#table - user_contacts
id       -      user_id     -   contacts_id    -   created_date
 1                1                  2             2020-02-26 08:43:26
 2                1                  3             2020-02-26 08:43:26
 3                1                  5             2020-02-26 08:43:26
 4                3                  4             2020-02-26 08:43:26
 5                3                  5             2020-02-26 08:43:26
 6                7                  2             2020-02-26 08:43:26
```

What i am trying to a accomplish is retrieve all contacts_id from user_contacts where the user_id is not equal to user_id = 1 which user Jon-1 so this must looks like

```
#retrieved data
 user_id - full_name  - image
   4       Man-4        Man-placeholder.png
   6       Led-6        Led-placeholder.png
   7       Neo-7        Neo-placeholder.png
```

user_ids 6,7,4 must be retrieved because user_id = 1 does not have those ids in the user_contact table under column contacts_id
First Query

```
SELECT            u.user_id, u.full_name, u.image
FROM              user u
NATURAL LEFT JOIN user_contacts cnt
WHERE             cnt.contacts_id IS NULL
```

Second Query

```
SELECT user.user_id, user.full_name, user.image
FROM USER
WHERE user.user_id NOT IN (
SELECT user_contacts.contacts_id
FROM user_contacts
WHERE user_contacts.contacts_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Third Query

```
SELECT            u.user_id, u.full_name, u.image
FROM              user u
NATURAL LEFT JOIN user_contacts cnt
WHERE             cnt.contacts_id IS NULL
```

Comment: For me the result has to be 4, 5 and 2. I cant assume why there should be Led-6 in the result?

Comment: Strawberry. no they are not solving the problem

Comment: Can you check again your expected result?

Comment: If you check my post above. you see #retrieved data this is the correct retrieved data

Comment: So  i have tried all the queries above and most of them retrieving wrong data

Comment: Can you explain why user_ids 6 and 7 are in your expected results?

Comment: user_ids 6,7,4 must be retrieved because user_id = 1 does not have those ids in the user_contact table under column contacts_id

Comment: Thanks for the help #Strawberry. i got it work now

Comment: @ShareKnowledge this explanation in the comments should be edited inside your question because it describes better your requirement. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1c8d1e092f940b0c9b0e053050a2179c)

```
SELECT
   user_id, full_name, image
FROM
   user
WHERE NOT user_id in (SELECT contacts_id from user_contacts WHERE user_contacts.user_id=1)
  AND user_id <> 1
```

`WHERE NOT user_id in sub-query`: The sub-query will get the contact for user=1.

`AND user_id <> 1`:  this makes sure user 1 is not selected.

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select u.* from user u 
where user_id <> 1
and not exists (
  select 1 from user_contacts
  where user_id = 1 and contacts_id = u.user_id
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ADHRLpJ3oD9igfLTPmpH5/1).
Results:

```
| user_id | full_name | image               |
| ------- | --------- | ------------------- |
| 4       | Man-4     | Man-placeholder.png |
| 6       | Led-6     | Led-placeholder.png |
| 7       | Neo-7     | Neo-placeholder.png |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM user a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT uc.* 
         FROM user u 
         JOIN user_contacts uc 
           ON uc.user_id = u.user_id 
        WHERE u.full_name = 'Jon-1' 
     ) b 
    ON b.contacts_id = a.user_id 
 WHERE a.full_name <> 'Jon-1' 
   AND b.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks Strawberry it works fine. now it return user_ids 4,6,7

Comment: @ShareKnowledge I wouldn't have posted it if it didn't! ;-)